# Python ctypes TypeError while calling a DLL function

Tags: python, dll, typeerror, ctypes

I have a DLL which I load with ctypes CDLL and then I am calling DLL functions via python. Sadly I do not have the original DLL coding, however I have an C header file where the function INPUTS and OUTPUTS and their types can be seen.

When I checked the header file for the following function it says:

```
INT32 DllExport load_active(
/* OUT */                      INT32  *h_nw,
/* IN  */                      INT32   flags);
```

So I am trying to run the `load_active` function in python via:

```
import ctypes as ct
    
dll = ct.CDLL('example.dll')
dll.load_active.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), ct.c_int32]
dll.load_active.errcheck = _validate_result

h_nw = ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32)
flags = ct.c_int32(0)

status = dll.load_active(h_nw, flags)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    status = dll.load_active(h_nw, flags)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: expected LP_c_long instance instead of _ctypes.PyCPointerType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h_nw` is a type in your code where a value is expected. Try:

```
h_nw = ct.c_int32(0)
flags = ct.c_int32(0)

status = dll.load_active(ct.byref(h_nw), flags)
```

`h_nw` will then contain the value set by `load_active`.

Alternatively, `h_nw` can be set as

```
h_nw = ct.pointer(ct.c_int32())
```

and used as

```
status = dll.load_active(h_nw, flags)
```

if the pointer itself should be kept for any reason but is less efficient.

Comment: `h_nw = ct.pointer(ct.c_int32())` when I do that it works. Could you please add this alternative?

Comment: @oakca that’s not a recommended alternative.

Comment: @oakca Edited, but as Mark said, it is not the best practice (except maybe for special requirements).

Comment: @MarkTolonen could you eleborate more on this topic? Because the dll outputs a value to the location which the pointer directs, and I need to look up to that location again to retrieve the value. I guess when giving `byref(h_nw)` would also change the value of `h_nw` from 0 to the output of the dll and I can then use it after the dll function call. But I do not understand what would be the problem if I just reserv a location without a value on memory via `ct.pointer(ct.c_int32())`....

Comment: @oakca It’s more expensive to create the pointer than to pass by reference.